# UFT Bitmap Checkpoint issue

Tags: hp-uft

We are facing an issue with Bitmap Checkpoint validation in UFT 14. We have captured all our bitmap checkpoints and saved them into our repository. Now the issue is, checkpoints will pass only on the system where it's captured. If we try to run the same script with Bitmap checkpoint on another system it fails. All our autotest PC are VMs hosted on Citrix and VSphere servers. We run the script on Win 10 and Win7. We use the same system configuration and same screen resolution for all VMs. Any reasons why the same Bitmap Checkpoint may fail on different systems.
Might Network speed be an issue?

Does using the Insight object solve the problem? (We are less inclined to use it. Its not consistent)

Does the 'night light' option or any screen color calibration will impact the Bitmap Checkpoint?
Any better way for image comparison checkpoint, the specific portion of AUT we are testing needs image comparison only. The image doesn't contain text, there are some arrow symbols, which we need to check.